# docker RUN - not executing script

Tags: ruby, docker

Building a Docker image for a Ruby app using https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/ I have a skeleton project with an empty Gemfile, Gemfile.lock and a 1 line Ruby script (`test.rb`) like this:

```
File.open("success.txt", 'w') { |file| file.write("Success!") }
```

Note the Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ruby:2.1-onbuild
CMD ["./test.rb"]
```

However, when I build and run it using:

```
docker build -t test-ruby-app . 
docker run -it --name my-running-test-ruby-app test-ruby-app
```

I can see it's run and exited using `docker ps`. If attach to it using:

```
docker run --entrypoint=bash -it  <image id>
```

I can see the Ruby script has not run (there's no `success.txt` file).

I can run it manually (after attaching to the image) using `./test.rb` and it works as expected.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Add your Dockerfile to your question.

Comment: In your Dockerfile are you copying the file into the image? That two line Dockerfile doesn't show you doing it.

Comment: The `-onbuild` image variant does that. It actually copies it to `/usr/src/app`: https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/master/2.1/onbuild/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're running the script correctly? Shouldn't be

```
CMD ["ruby", "./test.rb"]
```

?

I mean, I can suppose the script has executable permission but it's not a shell script.

Comment: While I agree with this answer, I think there are actually two issues going on. The second is that they are testing for the file in a _new_ container. The file wouldn't exist in their test anyways. You should point that out in your answer.

Comment: Do you mean we don't know how the script is in the container? I presume volumes

Comment: Why not? We don't know. User didn't put a feedback

Comment: The command they used to test didn't mount any volume. I'm assuming they are copying the file into the image during build. Regardless if they do or mount it at runtime, the example still wouldn't work because it doesn't mount a volume.